# array.some() method issue using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, return

```js
var phaseOne = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "1",
    streetNumberHigh: "436",
    streetName: "barnhart",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "waynesburo",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "22980",
  }
];

var phaseOneExt = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "580",
    streetNumberHigh: "1002",
    streetName: "battlefield",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "fort defiance",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "24437",
  }
];

var phaseTwo = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "1",
    streetNumberHigh: "727",
    streetName: "bailey",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "fort defiance",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "24437",
  }
];

var phaseTwoCares = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "728",
    streetNumberHigh: "996",
    streetName: "bailey",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "fort defiance",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "24437",
  }
];

function parseAddressString(str) {
  var matches = str.match(
    /(?<streetNumber>\d+)\s+(?<streetName>[\w\s-]+)\s+(?<streetCode>\w+),?\s+(?<city>[\w\s-]+),?\s+(?<state>\w+),?\s+(?<zipCode>\d+)/
  );
  if (matches) {
    return matches.groups;
  }
  return false;
}

function doesStringMatch(a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().includes(b.toLowerCase());
}
function doesAddressMatchPhase(address, phase) {
  return (
    address &&
    +address.streetNumber >= +phase.streetNumberLow &&
    +address.streetNumber <= +phase.streetNumberHigh &&
    doesStringMatch(address.streetName, phase.streetName) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.streetCode, phase.streetCode) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.city, phase.city) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.state, phase.state) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.zipCode, phase.zipCode)
  );
}

function isEligible(str) {
  var address = parseAddressString(str);
  var phases = [phaseOne, phaseOneExt, phaseTwo, phaseTwoCares];
  var x;
  for (x = 0; x < phases.length; x++) {
    console.log(phases[x]);
    console.log(address);
    phases[x].some(function (phase) {
      doesAddressMatchPhase(address, phase);
    });
  }
}

function addressValidation() {
  var str = document.getElementById("address").value,
    eligible = isEligible(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = eligible ? "true" : "false";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');

/* Global */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
}

#address-checker {
    height:25vh;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -3vh;
    padding: 3vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.checker-container {
    height: 25vh;
}

.address-header {
    padding: 3vh 0 2vh 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2277AE;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: clamp( 1.5rem, 3.5vw, 3.5rem);
}

.address-checker-input {
    padding: 1vh 0;
}

.address-box {
    margin: 1.5vh 0 0 10vw ;
    width: 60%;
    padding: .75rem 0 .75rem .5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: #2277AE 2px solid;
    color: #2277AE;
}

.address-box:hover {
    border-color: #FEA00B;
    transition: .2s;
}

.go-btn {
  background-color: #2277AE;
  padding: .75rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: #2277AE 2px solid;
  color: #fff;
}

.go-btn:hover {
    border-color: #FEA00B;
    background-color: #FEA00B;
    transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  
<section id="address-checker">
      <div class="checker-container">
        <h1 class="address-header">
          Is fiber to the home available for you?
        </h1>
        <div class="address-checker-input">
            <input
              id="address"
              type="text"
              name="searchaddress"
              placeholder="Street Address, City, State, Zip Code"
              class="address-box"
            />
            <button class="go-btn" onclick="addressValidation()">Go</button>
        </div>
        <p id="demo"></p>
      </div>
</section>

</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

I am currently building a javascript tool that takes an address as an input and compares it against a makeshift database of addresses within a service area. im using the array.some() method to loop through each of the objects properties within each phase array of the service area. i also need it to look through each phase if the previous returns false. because im using a for loop to loop through each of the phase arrays the return needed in the .some method causes my function to exit on the first loop. the issue is within the isEligible(str) function. in the code snippet attached is the code broken. i can get it to work if i put return in front of the last two lines of the function but it wont let the loop continue if the address is not found within the first phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `eligible = isEligible(str);` is a logic error. `eligible` will always be `undefined` because `isEligible()` has no return value. (I had to say that, although your comments indicate you know that).

To fix this, return the result from `doesAddressMatchPhase()` and store the result of the `.some()` return in a variable. Then directly after the `.some()` call, test if that variable is true, if so break the loop and return that variable immediately. Otherwise, wait until the end of the function to return the default false.

Here is the working solution:

```js
var phaseOne = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "1",
    streetNumberHigh: "436",
    streetName: "barnhart",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "waynesburo",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "22980",
  }
];

var phaseOneExt = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "580",
    streetNumberHigh: "1002",
    streetName: "battlefield",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "fort defiance",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "24437",
  }
];

var phaseTwo = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "1",
    streetNumberHigh: "727",
    streetName: "bailey",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "fort defiance",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "24437",
  }
];

var phaseTwoCares = [
  {
    streetNumberLow: "728",
    streetNumberHigh: "996",
    streetName: "bailey",
    streetCode: "rd",
    city: "fort defiance",
    state: "va",
    zipCode: "24437",
  }
];

function parseAddressString(str) {
  var matches = str.match(
    /(?<streetNumber>\d+)\s+(?<streetName>[\w\s-]+)\s+(?<streetCode>\w+),?\s+(?<city>[\w\s-]+),?\s+(?<state>\w+),?\s+(?<zipCode>\d+)/
  );
  if (matches) {
    return matches.groups;
  }
  return false;
}

function doesStringMatch(a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().includes(b.toLowerCase());
}
function doesAddressMatchPhase(address, phase) {
  return (
    address &&
    +address.streetNumber >= +phase.streetNumberLow &&
    +address.streetNumber <= +phase.streetNumberHigh &&
    doesStringMatch(address.streetName, phase.streetName) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.streetCode, phase.streetCode) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.city, phase.city) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.state, phase.state) &&
    doesStringMatch(address.zipCode, phase.zipCode)
  );
}

function isEligible(str) {
  var address = parseAddressString(str);
  var phases = [phaseOne, phaseOneExt, phaseTwo, phaseTwoCares];
  var x;
  let found = false;
  for (x = 0; x < phases.length; x++) {
    found = phases[x].some(function (phase) {
      return doesAddressMatchPhase(address, phase);
    });
    if(found) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return found;
}

function addressValidation() {
  var str = document.getElementById("address").value,
    eligible = isEligible(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = eligible ? "true" : "false";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');

/* Global */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
}

#address-checker {
    height:25vh;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -3vh;
    padding: 3vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.checker-container {
    height: 25vh;
}

.address-header {
    padding: 3vh 0 2vh 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2277AE;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: clamp( 1.5rem, 3.5vw, 3.5rem);
}

.address-checker-input {
    padding: 1vh 0;
}

.address-box {
    margin: 1.5vh 0 0 10vw ;
    width: 60%;
    padding: .75rem 0 .75rem .5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: #2277AE 2px solid;
    color: #2277AE;
}

.address-box:hover {
    border-color: #FEA00B;
    transition: .2s;
}

.go-btn {
  background-color: #2277AE;
  padding: .75rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: #2277AE 2px solid;
  color: #fff;
}

.go-btn:hover {
    border-color: #FEA00B;
    background-color: #FEA00B;
    transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  
<section id="address-checker">
      <div class="checker-container">
        <h1 class="address-header">
          Is fiber to the home available for you?
        </h1>
        <div class="address-checker-input">
            <input
              id="address"
              type="text"
              name="searchaddress"
              placeholder="Street Address, City, State, Zip Code"
              class="address-box"
              value="200 barnhart rd waynesburo, va 22980"
            />
            <button class="go-btn" onclick="addressValidation()">Go</button>
        </div>
        <p id="demo"></p>
      </div>
</section>

</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: awesome thank you! such a simple fix i guess i spent to much time staring at it to see how easy the solution was haha